# Javascript object trailing comma and different behavior when page is called as localhost and non localhost. Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, browser

I created simple html page with javascript object (test.html):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        myObj = { name: "object name", };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>simple text</p>
     <script type="text/javascript">
           alert(myObj.name);
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Displaying in any browser as http://localhost/test.html works fine. localhost is our lab-sql server. But when I try to display the same page on the same computer as http://lab-sql/test.html browsers (IE10, IE11, FF50) causes error:

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
test.html, line 4 character 40
SCRIPT5009: 'myObj' is undefined 
test.html, line 9 character 12
```

(line 4, characer 40 is after trailing comma; "myObj is undefined" is consequence of previous error)

Chrome works on both cases.

Why such different behaviour?
How to deal with such error in case of third party js libraries?
Or am I doing something wrong?

(I'm unsuccesfully trying to use angular-gantt libraries, due to the problem described.)

Comment: Are you **absolutely certain** you're seeing this in Firefox? I understand it in IE, but not in anything else.

Comment: The IE thing is because of IE's brain-dead default setting for intranets, which is to use "compatibility mode" (compatibility with previous broken versions of IE, not standards). The solution for IE is to make it not do that with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`. But it doesn't explain Firefox.

Comment: IE doesn't like trailing commas. It is expecting for another property. Chrome just ignores them. Identify inside the library the object with this mistake and override this object variable with another one which omits the last comma.

Comment: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/02/02/how-internet-explorer-8-document-mode-affects-javascript/

Comment: @quirimmo: Dangling commas on object initializers are supported in IE8 and above, and are part of the ES5 specification (December 2009).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yep I know they are allowed, and also as functions parameters. sorry, older versions of IE I meant. Then using the compatibility mode it may give that error

Comment: @quirimmo: *"...and also as functions parameters..."* That's **brand** new, in the upcoming ES2017 spec. Before that, they were forbidden.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yes, this comes from the new specs. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

Btw, as I said above, the issue should be related with IE compatibility mode in my opinion

Comment: T.J. Crowder: I have done some more tests and still have problem with firefox (and IE). But problem with FF looks like computer/system depended - on Win2012 std, works FF fine (on Win7 did not - both is 32bit, last version (53...))

Comment: Adding meta tag makes IE working. Thanks!